# Manually calculating norm

Tags: c++, norm

I have this code shown below which is supposed to manually calculate the norm of a randomlly generated vector. However, I keep getting the output being printed to the terminal as 0. Why is the case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

double ComputeNorm(const vector<double>& x) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (auto a : x) {
        double result = result + a*a;
    }
    return sqrt(result);
}


int main() {
    // Declare variables
#if 0
    int n;
    cin >> n
#else
    int n = 1000;
#endif

    if (n == 0) {
        cout << "N must be > 0" << endl;
    }

    vector<double> x(n, 0.0);

    // Seed the random number generate with the current epoch time
    srand(time(0));

    // Generate random numbers and print them to the screen
    generate(x.begin(), x.end(), [] { return (double)rand()/RAND_MAX; });

    // Print out the values computed by BLAS and manually
//    cout << "BLAS Norm:   " << cblas_dnrm2(n, &x[0], 1) << endl;
    cout << "Manual norm: " << ComputeNorm(x) << endl;
//    cout << "x(n): " << x[n] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double result = result + a*a;` is yet another `result`, not that `double result = 0.0;`

Comment: [Norm!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXED2AVlbR0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
        double result = result + a*a;
```

This declares a new variable inside the loop, so the other `result` variable doesn't change, which is why 0 is returned.
To fix it just do `result = result + a*a` or `result += a*a`:

```
double ComputeNorm(const vector<double>& x) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (auto a : x) {
        result = result + a*a;
    }
    return sqrt(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop in your `ComputeNorm` function, you have been redeclaring `result` in every iteration, while the `result` outside of you loop was never changed.

Instead, you might want `result = result + a*a` there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, but what I want to comment is that you are declaring the local variable `result`twice  inside the function `ComputeNorm.

That may be the root of your problem.